# Merge smaler pages to larger ones

Tags: merge

My problem is, I have A6 pages, but for printing I need A4 pages. The A6 pages are supposed to combine to A5 pages (2 A6 pages on front, two on back, so you can fold it in half). And for printing I'd need two of those A5 documents to be combined to an A4 page. Manually doing so would be very time consuming, as I have several versions of the one A5 document that I create with datatool. Overall there are over 200 pages.

Is there a viable option to do this in (Lua)LaTeX, that also works with quite complex documents (several custom environments, page background coloring etc.)?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) or the [`pgfmorepages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages) packages.

Comment: Actually, I can do it using the printer driver.  Use the scaling option: multiple pages per sheet and auto rotate.

Comment: See also [`pdfjam`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam) which is a wrapper to `pdfpages`. If needed, you could do several runs to combine a combination of a combination of …

Comment: pgfmorepages looks (at first glance) exactly like what I'm looking for. I wanted to prevent having to create a PDF and then modifying that. Also doing it in software and not just via printer drivers gives the ability to check if everything is positioned the right way. Anybody knows if pgfmorepages is compatible with LuaLaTeX? I remember pgftricks making trouble when directly creating PDFs, but never used TikZ, so not sure how that behaves.

Comment: sadly I don't really see how to do this complex of a task with any of the recommendations. Also I can't find any program that would really help with that task. Anybody got guides or recommendations?